# How do I cd to a symlink in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've created a symbolic link like so:

```
PS C:\dev\bin> cmd /c mklink "wd" c:\dev\code
symbolic link created for wd <<===>> c:\dev\code
```

OK, simple. So then I try to cd to it:

```
PS C:\dev\bin> cd wd
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'wd' because it does not exist.

PS C:\dev\bin> cd .\wd
Set-Location : Cannot find path '.\wd' because it does not exist.

PS C:\dev\bin> cd \wd
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'C:\wd' because it does not exist.
```

It is soooo much easier to do this in Linux. How do I actually cd to a symlink in PowerShell?

(It seems like a simple question, but the first 3 pages of google results didn't have an answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct command to link a directory is

```
cmd /c mklink /D link target
```

Check out 'mklink /?' for other options.

Comment: That did it. So what on earth did I create when I did it without the /D? You'd think that would have errored, since c:\dev\code is not a file.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using the [PowerShell Comuunity Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx). It adds the commands `New-Symlink`, `New-Junction`, `New-Hardlink`, and `Get-ReparsePoint`. It also adds some aliases for things like `ln` so you can just use the Linux syntax.

Comment: Huh?? cmd /c mklink is the command to make the symlink. Or did you miss that this is in Powershell?

Comment: `cmd /c` should not change the working directory unless specifically asked to. It is required here because `mklink` is a *cmd* builtin.

Comment: Sorry, I did miss that, I have revised my answer. This is what I use.

Comment: Just to clarify, 'cmd' is not part of powershell, that is the reg windows shell, although hopefully down the road we get more robust symlink capability in powershell, or any capability for that matter, b/c right now there is none!